# Finding proximal operator of square distance function to a closed convex a set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> **Problem:** Given $C$ is a closed convex set in E (Euclidean space in
> $\mathbb{R}^n$). Consider the distance function $$d_C(x) = \inf\{\Vert
>  x-c \Vert : c\in C\}$$ Verify that the proximal operator of $d_C^2$ is
> $$\dfrac{1}{2}(P_C(x)+x),$$
> where $P_C(x)$ is the projection of $x$ on to $C$.

**My attempt:** Firstly, we have
$$\text{prox}_{d_C^2}(x) = (\text{Id} + \partial d_C^2)^{-1}(x).$$
Consider function
\begin{align*}
   (\text{Id} + \partial d_C^2)(u)& = u + \partial d_C^2(u). \tag{1}
  \end{align*}
Since $d_C^2$ is differentiable then
\begin{align*}
  \partial d_C^2(u)& = \nabla d_C^2(u) = 2u - 2P_C(u) \tag{2}
  \end{align*}
From (1) and (2), we claim that
$$(\text{Id}+\partial d_C^2)(u) = 3u - 2P_C(u).$$
So, for $x \in E$ we have
$$(\text{Id} + \partial d_C^2)^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(x+2P_C(u)\right)$$
Therefore
$$\text{prox}_{d_C^2}(x) = \dfrac{1}{3}(x + 2P_C(u)).$$
I stuck here since I can make $\text{prox}d_C^2$ to a function of only variable $x$. May you tell me why I'm wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your expression seems to be the proximal operator to $\frac12 d_C^2$.

For $x \in E$ let $u := (x + P_C(x))/2$. In order to verify $u = \operatorname{prox}_{\frac12 d_C^2}(x)$, we have to check
$$
x \in u + \partial \left(\frac12 d_C^2\right)(u).$$
By using $P_C(u) = P_C(x)$, this is easy to verify.